# How to execute a directive right when rendering DOM in VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, directive

I'm trying to define a directive and I need to be executed right when DOM is rendered.

I was reading about different hooks, but inserted () or update () hook doesnt do the trick.
This is my directive:

```
Vue.directive('validation-directive', {
  bind (el, binding, vNode) {
    addValidation(el, binding)
  },
  inserted (el, binding, vNode) {
    addValidation(el, binding)
  },
  stopProp (event) { event.stopPropagation() }
})

function addValidation (el, binding) {
  console.log(el)
}
```

Anyone knows how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: `mounted()` is not okay?

Comment: Mounted is a hook for a component right?, Im refering to a directive hook @kissu

Comment: Looking [at this](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/custom-directives.html#_3-x-syntax), `inserted` is just another name to `mounted` hence why it was renamed to `mounted` in Vue3. I've suggested using regular `mounted` because you should achieve what you'd like with a `mounted` is you want it to be done when mounting. I'm not sure what you're trying to do but maybe you need hack it with a [`this.$nextTick`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick). Also, if you're willing to have some client-side validation, give a try to [VeeValidate](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3).

Comment: Have you tried the `update()` hook ? Or did you try `Vue.nextTick()` inside your `inserted()` hook?